# Installing IPA file on iphone using iFunbox, iTunes

Tags: ios, windows, plist, ipa

I have .ipa application and I'm installing it to my Iphone from windows pc, I've tested with iFunbox, iTunes and iDiawi , I'm getting this error

[image]

iDiawi shows this error, what it means and how can i fix that to install on my iOS device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Shows Three scenario.

1st-

Got to your Developer Account and check this provisioning profile is not valid its shows Invalid.

2nd-

Your certificates is Expired this also check in keychain access.

3rd-

This Iphone device UDID does not include in this Provisioning Profile.

Comment: This app is not developed by me, how can i check from app-s ipa file, using ipaEditor or something like that to chack my udid in app?

or I need to contact with developer of this app to check him my UDID or Provisioning profile.